# Select distinct by column in Active Record - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 tables:

```
1. Post table (:id, :content)
2. Comment table (:id, :post_id, :content)
```

I'm using this code:

```
@result = Comment.where("content LIKE :query", query: "%#{@keyword}%")
```

`@result` has more dupplicated posts, how can I select unique collection by `DISTINCT :post_id` 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: how can there be duplicated values? a post can have many comments where post_id is the same. a post can have 5 comments including the text "foo"

Comment: More than 1 comment @huanson

Answer (score 2):

just for the record another solution

```
@result = Comment.where("content LIKE :query", query: "%#{@keyword}%").group(:post_id)
```